# Does select return last inserted row while autocommit set false?

Tags: java, mysql, autocommit

Say I have a table named ***users*** and a column named ***username***  with the format *user1, user2 ..*

I want to insert users into this table in a loop and value of every entry depends on the one's before. Value of the new entry is generated by the alphabetically greatest entry in the table, namely ***users***.

Since it's possible in JDBC API to `getGeneratedKeys` after an insert while AutoCommit set to false;

In a situation like given below:

```
connection.setAutoCommit(false);
while(someCondition)
{
    ResultSet rs = connection.createStatement("select max(username) from users").executeQuery();
    if(rs.next())
    { 
        name= rs.getString("username"); //returns user1
    }
    String newName = generateNewName(name); // simply makes user1 -> user2

    connection.createStatement("insert into users (name,...) values ("+newName+",...)").executeUpdate(); ///and inserts..
}
```

does the **select** query return the last inserted value 
or
it returns the max column in the table *before* I start the loop ?

Comment: It will return the current max value. A different session (= a different connection, e.g. a different user/app) might see the old value though, until you commit the values, so this is only safe to use in a single user environment. Also be aware that `user2 > user10`, because it is lexigraphically ordered, so you might get a different max value than you expect.

Comment: @Solarflare thanks for the reply. If you could add any doc reference and make it an answer I will accept it. By the way the user example was just an analogy to what I actually try to achieve, thanks for the warning though.

Answer (score 0):

First, to make sure you see all changes on the database immediately prefer TransactionIsolation of READ_UNCOMMITED over using auto commit. Alternatively using auto commit everywhere would do the job, too.

Once you made sure you see every db change immediately, the database will send you the maximum user from some time *during* the selects execution. But once you actually receive the result there might be additional users created by others threads. Thus this will only work for a single thread working and most likely that doesn't make any sense nowadays.

**TL:DR**
No, don't do it!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, as I commented above the scenario I suggested was just an analogy and obviously doesnt reflect the situation at my hand. The reason I asked the question is that I wasn't able to find any documented behaviour about the situation, thus not the answer I expect. However, about the multithreaded approach, I had no idea about there could be a risk like that so I appreciate the info.